# Strange results of full-text MySQL search, need an explanation

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

my SQL query
`SELECT keyword

FROM table

WHERE MATCH (keyword)

AGAINST ('eco*' IN BOOLEAN MODE);`
matches cells with these words:`economy`,`ecology`,`echoscopy`(why?),`echo`(why?) etc.

other SQL query
`SELECT keyword

FROM table

WHERE MATCH (keyword)

AGAINST ('eci*' IN BOOLEAN MODE);`
matches cell with the word:`echidna`.

Yet **both** queries don't match word `ectoplasm`.

Why does `echo`, `echoscopy` match `'eco*'` and `echidna` matches `'eci*'`?

I see key element in this problem being letter combination "**ch**".

Why does it work this way and how can I avoid this kind of matching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem (feature?) was in the collation. "c" and "ch" were treated equal because of utf8_lithuanian_ci collation.

*Edit:*

Changing collation to utf8_unicode_ci fixes only certain issues.

The real solution is to use **utf8_bin**, which matches binary values of each character, meaning it's:

- case sensitive
- diacritics sensitive

Answer (score 0):

The reason that it matches is that MATCH ... AGAINST is using regular expressions, and the * means, that the preceding char ("o") can be there from 0 to 9999999999999999999^ times. What you meant to match is

```
eco.*
```

Will match "eco" and "ecology" but not "echo".

```
eco.+
```

Will match "ecology" and "eco system" but not "eco" nor "echo".

Comment: MATCH ... AGAINST does not use regular expressions, it does full text search. See Adomas's answer for the real explanation of what happened.

Comment: Did you notice Adoma is the OP? So I guess he already "noticed".. Regards.. :-)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try this

```
SELECT keyword FROM table WHERE keyword LIKE 'eco%';
```

Comment: Sorry, can't use LIKE - it's much too slow.

Comment: One should really avoid LIKE queries as much as possible, especially on large datasets. A FULLTEXT index is what is needed and that is what the OP needed help with.